# Return only array data without return the function itself using Array.prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, extend

I'm writing a function to do some data filtering. I write this:

```
Array.prototype.keyFilter = function ()
{
    var dta = this;

    for ( i in dta )
    {
        console.log( dta[i] );
    };
};

console.log( ['green','yellow','blue'].keyFilter('type') );
```

And the return is:

```
green
yellow
blue
function ()
    {
        var dta = this;

        for ( i in dta )
        {
            console.log( dta[i] );
        };
    }
undefined
```

OK, I get the array data ...PLUS the function itself and an "undefined". How to get only the array data using Array.prototype ??

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should use a regular `for` loop to loop arrays, not `for...in`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `for...in`, which iterates over the enumerable properties of the object, including the function you've added to the prototype. That is [expressly *not* how you're meant to iterate over arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

If you want to iterate over an array, you should use a simple `for` loop, and count from `0` to `length - 1`...

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
  console.log(this[i]);
}
```

Or, use `forEach`:

```
this.forEach(function (i) {
  console.log(i);
});
```

The "undefined" part is your outer `console.log(...)` logging the return value of your function, which is `undefined` because you don't return anything.